# How to use a service of mode synchronous in android with loopj

Tags: android, web-services, asynchronous, synchronous, loopj

Good day,

In this moment I'm developing an app that use a webservice of mode Async, but I have some problems with it.
I need use the webservice of mode ***synchronous*** for continue with my principal thread without any problem.

Thanks so much!!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please read ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Same way as we use **async-http-client** for **loopj**, but it will **block** the UI till completion.

```
SyncHttpClient syncHttpClient = new SyncHttpClient();
syncHttpClient.setTimeout(timeout);
syncHttpClient.post(url, params, responseHandler);

syncHttpClient .post("http://example.com", params, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            // you can do something here before request starts                    
        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
            // success logic here
        }


        @Override
        public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, Throwable e, JSONObject errorResponse) {
           // handle failure here
        }

    });
```